# mongodb insert unexpected identifier

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, nosql

It's really hard to see what went wrong in mongo, what's wrong with my insert below?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with single quote (') you are using single quote for start and end block and also there is single quote(') in the description [**cursed,it's know as**]

Either use double quote(") to enclose data or try to html encode your data before saving.